# How to remove href attribute if the link matches current webpage URL?

Tags: jquery

I have a static file called `header.html`, which is embedded in my Java servlet and is displayed on top of all the webpages generated by the servlet -

[image: screenshot]

It displays an UL list acting as a navigation menu.

It is displayed same on all pages, but if a page is already displayed, I would like to remove the link pointing to it.

Unfortunately, my code does not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[href='" + window.location.href + "']").removeAttr("href");
});
```

```css
.center {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#navigation {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navigation > li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="center">My web page</h1>
<h3 class="center">My motto</h3>

<div class="center">
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="/en/ws/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/en/ws/top">Top</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68853864/how-to-remove-href-attribute-if-the-link-matches-current-webpage-url">Stackoverflow</a></li>
        <li><a href="/en/ws/android">Android</a></li>
        <li><a href="/en/ws/ios">iOS</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It works when I use a hardcoded URL, but not when I try to replace it by `window.location.href`

Please suggest a better jQuery code. If the selector `a[href='" + window.location.href + "']"` cannot be used, then should I maybe iterate through the links, which are children of `#navigation` and then remove `href` if it matches the current page URL? And how to make it work with relative URLs (like `/en/ws/android`)?

**UPDATE:**

And here is the link to my [real webpage](https://wordsbyfarber.com/en/ws/android) where my code fails to work.

Comment: It's not working in your snippet because it runs in an iframe with a different URL>

Comment: Ok, makes sense, but it also does not work on [my real webpage](https://wordsbyfarber.com/en/ws/android) either.

Comment: `window.location.href` might not match exactly. It could have query parameters or a hash. So you should use a method that isn't so specific.

Comment: This is the element: `<a href="/en/ws/android">Android</a>`. It's `href` attribute is just `/en/ws/android`, which isn't equal to `https://wordsbyfarber.com/en/ws/android`

Comment: You could use `window.location.pathname` instead of `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your real page, the `href` is just the pathname portion of the URL, not the full URL. So use that in your selector.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[href='" + window.location.pathname + "']").removeAttr("href");
});
```

You could also use a filter:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[href]").filter(function() {
        return this.href == window.location.href;
    }).removeAttr("href");
});
```

The `href` attribute is just what's in the HTML, but the `href` property is the fully-resolved URL.

Comment: Thank you Barmar for your responses (upvoted) and the detailed answer. For the `filter()` - is there a way to loop only through the `a` elements, which are (indirect) children of `#navigation` ?

Comment: Change the selector to `#navigation a[href]`